# Does the construction "X is not as Y as Z" imply that X is less Y than Z, or just not equivalent?

Tags: meaning, construction

For example, if I say "pop tarts are not as delicious as sushi" does that necessarily imply that I think pop tarts are less delicious than sushi or just that they have a different level of deliciousness?  Could it imply that I think pop tarts are, in fact, more delicious than sushi?

Thanks for any comments you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I say "pop tarts are not as delicious as sushi" does that necessarily imply that I think pop tarts are less delicious than sushi

It does *imply* it, but does not *state* it. The difference is that an implication can be cancelled. For example:

- *"He is not as smart as his brother"* implies "he is less smart than his brother"
- *"He is not as smart as his brother -- he is much smarter!"* outright states that he is smarter than his brother, cancelling the implication made in the first half.

Comment: The second example is kind of like a joke, because the second clause is a surprising contradiction to the implication.